# Find control within listbox template WPF

Tags: wpf

Loop through `Listbox` `items` and try to get `checkbox` control but i can't find. My `XAML` code is as below.

```
<ListBox Height="119" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=mastertable}" Margin="193,10,0,0" Name="lstMyItems" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden" Width="120" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Normal">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTemplete">
                                <CheckBox Name="chkIsselect"   Margin="0,5,0,0"  Content="{Binding ItemName}"  Click="chkIsselect_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
```

and c# Code

```
  for (int i = 0; i < lstMyItems.Items.Count; i++)
 {
         // Here I need acces to Checkbox.
 }
```

Comment: What do you want to achive? Is it data bound? What does your template look like?

Comment: http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-access-a-control-placed-inside-listbox-itemtemplate-in-wp7

Comment: Why do you need `CheckBox`? Or you need just to check if it's checked or not?